# Getting "Subscript out of range"

Tags: excel, vbscript

I'm getting "Subscript out of range" while I'm running this code. (problem is in the definition of `LastRow`)

```
my_new_string = "xyz"
my_old_string = "abc"

For Each objsheet1 In objworkbook1.Sheets
  With objsheet1
    If .Name = "Name1" Then
      On Error Resume Next
      LastRow = .Cells.Find("*",.Range("A1"),xlPart,xlFormulas,xlByRows,xlPrevious,False).Row
      MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Source & ") - " & Err.Description

      For i = 1 To LastRow Step 1
        For j = 1 To 10 Step 1
          If InStr(1, .Cells(i, j).Value, my_old_string) Then
            .Cells(i, j).Value = Replace(.Cells(i, j).Value, my_old_string, my_new_string)
          End If
        Next
      Next 
    End If
  End with
Next
```

What does this error mean please and how can I fix it?

Comment: which line causes the problem?

Comment: LastRow = .Cells.Find("*",.Range("A1"),xlPart,xlFormulas,xlByRows,xlPrevious,False).Row

Comment: no, I just added it to get more description about the error, I added it before getting the error, you can remove it and check

Comment: The duplicated question seems to answer this directly. I was puzzled by this until I noticed the `vbscript` tag.

Comment: These are my constants: Const xlPart = 2
Const xlFormulas = -4163
Const xlByRows = 1
Const xlPrevious = 2   I'm not using the xlvalues as what noticed in the other question

Comment: With those constants defined in your script you should be getting a different error now (because `xlPart` and `xlFormulas` are in the wrong order).